# How to change style of css for particular div?

Tags: css

I want to change the style of my `li` tag for particular `div` means I want to show that element for whole page,but at start I don't want to show that `li` tag. I want to change style of that tag.

```
<ul id="butons_right">
        <li>
            <a href="#service" id="toTop" rel="nofollow">Top</a>
        </li>
        <li>
             <div id="close"></div>
        </li>
</ul>
```

this is my that element which dont want to show it at start of page. I want to change its style to display:none.

Can anybody provide me any solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please could you clarify _which_ `<li>` you want to change the style of. Do you want the element to be displayed in response to a particular event (for example `:hover`)?

Answer (score 0):

In CSS:

```
#butons_right>li {
    display: none;
}
```

However assign something to that tag so you can select that particular tag. I'm not sure which `li` tag you want to hide.

If it's the first `li` tag, use `li:first-child`. If not, assign a class to it, say, `hidden`, and then use `.hidden` (`#butons_right>.hidden`, or just `.hidden`).

Comment: Without a clear question, how can you give a clear answer? It would be better to ask which `<li>` as a comment on the question first.

Comment: I did cover all cases though, did I not?

Comment: True, but if this answer was accepted, how would future visitors know which part was correct?

Comment: @andyb Future visitors will probably have trouble understanding which tag he wants to hide anyway, just like I did, thus my answer is perfect for such circumstance. You're splitting hairs.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [nth-child](http://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/) css selector to select a specific `li` though CSS:

Here is the example:

```
#butons_right > li:nth-child(1){
  /*your css*/
}
```

And to hide the first `li` use the `display:none` property in css.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial code should state

```
selector {
visibility:hidden;
}
```

Once the document is loaded or whatever event of your interest arise, you can modify the style with

```
selector {
visibility:visible;
}
```

The visibility property has the benefit of not re-arrange your lay out boxes.
The display property , gets out from the flow your element when is set to none. When you modify it again to return to visibility, the lay out will be affected

**Which selector to use**

It depends on your preferences/needs
You could apply an id or a class in your markup as "close" and the in your css use

```
#butons_right li.close {
visibility:hidden;
}
```

This selector is well implemented cross browser an will work fine with quite strong specificity.
If not you may use (if it is suitable) first-child, last-child or nth-child(n) to target your desired li element